# How to send file from (windows) PC to android/ios using NFC?

Tags: android, ios, windows, nfc, file-transfer

I want to create an application that would allow a file to be transferred from a (windows) based PC to an Android/IOS smartphone using NFC. However I couldn't find a good place to start so I was wondering if anyone here had some experience with this type of file transfer.

I would like the application too:

- function as a 'printer' on the pc side
- open a custom app after the transfer is done where the file can be managed/reviewed
- be limited to one tap for the users convenience

Any tips on where to start would be welcome. I was thinking about using an NFC Arduino module as a basis and then try to figure out how to interact with Android beam and CoreNFC but maybe you guys have some better solution?

Comment: First thing, get an NFC capable Windows PC or an external NFC transmitter for a PC.

Comment: I read some stuff about the ACR122U but I was also thinking that a custom arduino device might be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

NFC file transfer is not possible with iOS yet. Apple have allowed only reading from the NFC chip so far and haven’t announced any plans to open this up further.

Comment: Okay so the best approach for this would be to use the pc to reprogram a tag and then read the data (let's say an url) from that tag and transfer it to the phone? To retrieve the actual file there? (As I would be able to read NDEF messages right)
Or use it to setup a bluetooth connection and send the file that way